# How to call a phone number with web Skype?

Tags: skype-for-web, voip, phone-number

Skype has a web interface at https://web.skype.com
I have a lot of credit left and want to call an international number.
Surprisingly, I see no dialpad or anywhere to call numbers.

I tried adding a contact named after the phone number, but the call does not even try, it drops *immediately*. I also have that person on Skype with the same phone number listed as "Mobile" in the "Contact details", but the call button is disabled, presumably because that person is not connected to Skype right now.

How to call a phone number with web Skype?

Comment: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34634/how-do-i-call-phones-in-skype-for-web may or may not help

Answer (score 1):

Web Skype can not call phones until you install a special plugin.

The plugin download will be shown when opening web Skype if your web browser supports it. Unfortunately it does not support ChromeOS, Linux, WinRT, and only supports a few specific browsers on Windows and Mac.

After installing that plugin, a "Call phones" button appears on web Skype:

[image: Skype web call phones]

You can use it to dial to any international phone number (if you have credit).